# Bounty +50 on question from user with 22 rep?

Tags: discussion, bounties

As of right now (3/17/12 02:24 -07:00) [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9645350/building-a-simple-real-time-form-editor) has a +50 bounty from the OP, but the user has only 22 rep. How is this possible?

BTW, the question itself has 6 downvotes and is flagged "not a real question"

Comment: He's asked virtually [the same question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/139081/building-a-simple-real-time-form-editor) on Programmers. It *may* be abuse of the system to offer a bounty to prevent the question getting closed.

Comment: Maybe no bounties on questions of -3 or more?  Excluding meta?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Only [75 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties) is required to set bounties, and as soon as you offer the bounty, the points you outlaid are *immediately* removed from your reputation score.

So it's not hard to imagine that he had 75 reputation at one point (barely enough to set a bounty), and then set a 50 point bounty, which brought him back down to 25 reputation.

That's not *exactly* what happened here, because you said he only has 22 reputation at the time you posted the question, which is obviously a few points off from the required minimum of 25 that he should have. But that's easily explained through a downvote or two, or through the deletion of one of his posts that had received an upvote, *after* the bounty amount had been sliced off from his account reputation.

**Edit:** As further evidence that reputation can fluctuate rapidly (a consequence of [the recent changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/recent-reputation-history-changes)), the user now has 27 reputation. And that will probably change some more as the rest of the Meta crowd downvotes his question.

Comment: Thanks. I must have missed the fact that the bounty is subtracted at the time of offering